# Enable customer address override checkbox via api

Tags: api, netsuite, ipaas

We are using an iPaaS platform named Celigo to sync orders from our ecom platform into Netsuite. Our question is we want to override the default ship to address on a customers account with a new address from a new order that would be sync'ed into Netsuite.

However we are not able to find what field name is used to enable the Override checkbox on a customers default shipto address. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set the destination record field as 'shipoverride'. Data type = boolean, Hard-coded, use custom value, enter default value as F. [Setting in Celigo Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFcwG.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).